# How do I set up express gateway to securely connect with my services

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, express-gateway

I have currently configured [express-gateway](https://www.express-gateway.io/) to communicate with a service on my backend exposed on a unique port on my machine and it's working fine. The gateway serves as a **proxy** to the services and currently does some security checks and **jwt authentication**. Then, **only** authorized request (through jwt validation) gets sent to services as configured. However, I'm concerned that if I don't put some sort of authentication on my service, then anyone who knows the port (or URL) my service runs on can directly access it and bypass the gateway directly. I'm looking for a way I can set up a sort of auth between the gateway and the service (maybe through keys) so that only the gateway can communicate with the services and not any other client. I currently can't find anything in the [docs](https://www.express-gateway.io/docs/) specifically for that. Also, if there's something wrong with my architecture, I'd appreciate it if you could point it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path between Express Gateway and your back end should be on a private, encrypted network so there is no way for anyone to bypass the gateway.

With this architecture, you don’t need to authenticate on the server side, and if you use Express Gateway scopes, you don’t even need to check whether the user is authorized to perform the requested action.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I figured this out so I never came back. But big thanks all the same. :)